# HTTP session is not maintained between two localhosts (gwt/react client running on port 3000, local tomcat server running on 8080) bcz of CORS domain?

Tags: cookies

Did anybody faced the above issue, CORS cookie is not getting stored in the browser even after enabling the CORS on the server-side to accept the preflight request and return as accepted on the very first call. All the requests originate from clients who always hit the servers with a new HTTP session id. I felt like enabling the CORS works only against the secured domain like HTTPS, not HTTP.

I have verified the first request and response headers, the response has the proper JSESSIONID is passed as the Set-Cookie value. But the subsequent requests were not referencing this cookie.

Answer (score 1):

```
 solution 1: add this bean
       @Bean
        public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
        }
solution 2: add this to your controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:3000" })

**like this:**
 @CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:3000" })
public class RoleController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;
}
```